# How to remove subfolders keeping its content using batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Given a folder with several subdirectories, I want to move their contents to the top folder and remove the subdirectories. How can I do that on the Windows command line?

E.g. I have a folder named "Jack" in `D:`. It contains several subfolders and each subdirectory contains additional files (text files, PDF files, etc.), but no directories. I want to move all subfolders' files into "Jack", and remove the then empty subdirectories.
If duplicate file found do replace or do nothing, I need only one copy
I need to do this repeatedly, so a batch solution would be best.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take a moment to read the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) to learn how the site works.

Comment: How do you want to deal with naming collisions? Will there be `D:\Jack\A\1.pdf` and `D:\Jack\B\1.pdf`?

Comment: thanks,
I am using these at office,
File names are different, If same filename found just replace,
Thanks in advnce Mr. Beck

Comment: "**If same filename found just replace**"... to what?

Comment: Sorry,
I mean, Replace the file or do nothing,

thanks Mr. charan

Comment: You can use `xcopy` to do this. Type `xcopy /?` at the command prompt for usage information.

Comment: -1 Question shows no research effort. We expect users to do some research themselves, and you seem to be unwilling to do that.

Comment: Dear Beck,

I had searched in google last two days i couldn't get the result what i need, tried every result in my system, Nothing happens
I am doing  these things manually and daily using Cut & paste,
(pls note I am not a programmer and new to batch programs)

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a batch script.

```
for /f "delims==" %%k in ('dir D:\Jack\*.* /s /b') do copy "%%k" D:\Jack\ /Y
```